# C++ string outputs smiley faces

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to read a binary file to get its individual bit values. I'm doing so using the following function.

```
string readFileBytes(const char *name)
{
  ifstream fl(name);
  fl.seekg( 0, ios::end );
  size_t len = fl.tellg();
  char *ret = new char[len+1];    

  fl.seekg(0, ios::beg); 
  fl.read(ret, len);
  fl.close();    
  ret[len] = '\0';

  return ret;
  delete ret;
       }
```

This works fine. For the next part I'm taking each element of the array `ret` and using the following function I wrote to get the individual bit values.

```
string out;
for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
{


    for (int x =7; x >=0; x--)
    {
    out += ((ret[i]>>x) & 0x01);
    }       
}
```

If I have `cout << ((ret[i]>>x) & 0x01);` within the nested loop instead it prints the bit values perfectly. But when I have it as it is, and print the string (`out`), I get nothing but smiley faces.

Any ideas why?

Comment: at least the operating system is being nice to you with the smiley faces, my machine just boringly displays `NUL` `SOH` `NUL` `NUL`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
((ret[i]>>x) & 0x01)
```

evaluates to the integer `0` or `1` (i.e., numerical values of `0` or `1`). You need the character representing `0` and `1`. Try

```
out += '0' + ((ret[i]>>x) & 0x01);
```

Related: [Convert an int to ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629050/3093378)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't realised that.

Answer (score 1):

A binary 0 or 1 does not produce a char '0' or '1'. You need to put proper char codes into the output string.

Answer (score 1):

`return ret;delete ret;` This is wrong as well. Are there any warnings ? You are having `delete` after `return`.
If you are deleting a `char*` then you should use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Comment: OP probably shouldn't even be using char* anyways, `string` would more than likely suffice for this

Comment: @Alejandro probably he's using `char*` for the buffer passed to `ifstream::read`, then returning it as a `std::string` due to `std::string` implicit constructor that takes a `char*`. The problem is the memory leak, which can be avoiding by using `std::unique_ptr<char> ret(new char[len+1]);` instead.

Comment: @Alejandro and then using it with `ret.get()` where a the raw pointer is needed.

Comment: @Alejandro I'm using the char* because it's needed by ifstream.

Comment: @vsoftco doesn't the `ret[len] = '\0'` deal with the potential memory leak issue?

Comment: @nappyboi, no, at the end of the program (or if you invoke `readFileBytes(...)` multiple times) the memory allocated for `ret*` is not released.

Comment: @nappyboi `ifstream` can be used with `std::getline` which works with `std::string`

Comment: @Alejandro True. But wouldn't that ignore any bits that represent the a new line(`\n`), since `getline` uses this as the delimiter? In my case I need to read those bits too, so I went with `ifstream::read`