# Char Array Pointer Returns Incorrect (Current Year ctime)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, datetime, pointers

This function

```
char *uniqid()
{
    static char uniqid[13];

    time_t curTime = time(0);
    struct tm *time = gmtime(&curTime);

    //Year
    uniqid[0] = '1';
    uniqid[1] = '5';
    uniqid[2] = '\n';

    return uniqid;
}
```

when called in a cout returns "15" which it normally should, but when I do this

```
char *uniqid()
{
    static char uniqid[13];

    time_t curTime = time(0);
    struct tm *time = gmtime(&curTime);

    //Year
    uniqid[0] = ((time->tm_year + 1900) % 100) / 10;
    uniqid[1] = ((time->tm_year + 1900) % 100) % 10;
    uniqid[2] = '\0';

    return uniqid;
}
```

when called in a cout it returns weird icons.

Comment: `'1' != 1` do you see the difference?

Comment: `'1'` and `1` are different values.

Comment: In order to solve simply add `'0'`

Comment: so what can I do? This (char)((time->tm_year + 1900) % 100) / 10 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an int to ASCII character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629050/convert-an-int-to-ascii-character)

Comment: And the first version also only happens to be correct, because you do not explicitly terminate the string. Note that this is no C++ code, but C and in C++ you should use String types.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works now!

Comment: out of curiosity why static ?

Comment: A friend told me to use it. He said that after the function is returned all variables inside it are destroyed, so the pointer can't be pointing to the variable inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

`'1'` and `1` are different values.

To get `'1'` from `1`, just add `'0'`

```
uniqid[0] = ((time->tm_year + 1900) % 100) / 10;
uniqid[0] += '0';
uniqid[1] = (((time->tm_year + 1900) % 100) % 10) + '0';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`tm_year` is of int type right. You are assigning the int type to char. This results that strange icon. You need to convert that to char by adding 48(which is the ASCII code for zero) to it. Then the ints will be properly converted to char.

Comment: You don't need to know the code (ASCII or otherwise) for `'0'` to do the addition.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I didn't know that. I used to search for those ASCII codes for the characters.