# Changing the character inside a string to number

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a string a = "Hello world!", now for fun I wish to change the first letter in the string a to a number of my choosing. for example

```
string a = "Hello world!";
int x;
std:cin>>x;
a[0] = x;
cout << a;
```

Now what i want it to produce is "xello world!" x being the number i typed in, but instead I get a little smiley face.

Anyone seen anything similar and know how to fix it?

Also: Why can you even access a string like this string[] ? it's not a char array o.o

Comment: What if the decimal representation of the number is more than 1 digit long? For instance, you enter `123`, do you want the result to be `123ello world!`?

Comment: `a[0]='0'+x`. you should learn about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: _"it's not a char o.o"_ The [`std::string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) overload in fact returns a `char&`.

Comment: Try `char x = 'a'; x = 100;` and see what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Convert an int to ASCII character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629050/convert-an-int-to-ascii-character)

Comment: @BoBTFish I've used module to find out how many digits long the number is so no problem there :)

Comment: @fukanchik Yes this worked thanks :)

Comment: _"Why can you even access a string like this string[] ? it's not a char array"_ Well, no, it pretty much is, and its interface is deliberately constructed such that you can use it as one, because that's really useful and sensible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is a single digit number, do this instead:

```
a[0] = x + '0';
```

**EDIT**:

*Why this works*:

Each element in `string` is a `char`. A `char` is represented by an `integer`. You can check this up in the `ASCII table`. For example, `integer 48` represents `char '0'`, `integer 49` represents `char '1'`, etc. Thus, by adding your `integer x` to `char '0'`, you can get the digit `'x'` that you want.

*Why it might be dangerous*:

One reason that I could think of would be when writing to unallocated memory in an empty string, which might invoke undefined behavior.

You can then check if a string is empty with `string::empty()`. In this case,

```
if (!a.empty()) {...}
```

Comment: You should explain why this works. Also, why it is dangerous, and how to check the necessary prerequisite.

Comment: @Lincoln this worked however care to exaplin what BoBTFish was talking about? I'm intriqued

Comment: @3rdaccountQQ Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Using [string::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) and [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), this will work regardless if `x` is a single or multiple digit number:

```
string a = "Hello world!";
int x;
std:cin>>x;
a.replace(0, 1, std::to_string(x));
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/XYGDtN)

Comment: This is very intresting, I'm sure I'll use it in the future, however the optimal solution for my problem seems to be what Lincoln wrote

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer you could use the `at()` method in a try block as it is performing bounds checking and throws exception of type `std::out_of_range` if the access is invalid:
If you add `x + '0'` and `x` is higher than 9 it won't give you a number.
Look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
int main()
{
    std::string a { "Hello World" };
    int x {};
    std::cin >> x;
    try {
        a.at(0) = '0' + x;      // OOPS: '0' + 10 will give you ':'
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

A better solution is what @PaulMcKenzie answered, to use `std::to_string` and `string::replace`.