# Search for Char in String

Tags: c++

My code is returning zero instead of actually counting the number of instances of the digit that are actually in the number. I am confused about what I have done wrong.

```
int number_times_appear(int digit, int number)
{
    int total = 0;
    string stringNumber = to_string(number);
    char charDigit = digit;

    total = count(stringNumber.begin(), stringNumber.end(), charDigit);
    cout << total;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: `char charDigit = digit;` does not do what you think it does. Stop trying to write C++ based on guessing.

Comment: I saw someone do this on another forum. They described it as implicit type conversion.

Comment: And that's exactly what I'm talking about. Look up what the implicit conversion `int` -> `char` does before using it in your code.

Comment: Of course it converts (alongside a compiler warning you happily ignored), but still, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conversion is wrong you should do

```
char charDigit = '0' + digit;// to convert it to char
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629050/convert-an-int-to-ascii-character) for a detailed explanation

I also created an *Ideone* snippet [here](http://ideone.com/YOApaN)

Answer (score 1):

`char charDigit = digit;` does not do what you seem to think it does. This takes the value in `digit` and converts it into a character based on your character set (e.g. for American ASCII, [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). For example, a `digit` of `9` could actually search your string for tabs!

You want `char charDigit = '0'+digit;` instead because, to again use the example of ASCII, `'0'` evaluates to 48, as per the linked table, and the numbers `'1'`-`'9'` follow it as 49-57.

Comment: No, there is no ASCII involved in either of the conversions in this answer. The first is just an integer conversion, and the second is required to work for every supported character set, regardless of how the character set encodes `'0'`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Maybe technically correct, but OP is almost surely using ASCII, and is using it as a character, not a number, in `total = count(stringNumber.begin(), stringNumber.end(), charDigit);`, so I think you're being a little too pedantic...

Comment: @PeteBecker I've edited the answer for clarity regardless, see if that's what you meant by your comment. If not you'll need to explain yourself another way please