# How the following Decimal to Binary conversion code is working?

Tags: c++, stl, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I came across the following C++ code in the InterviewBit for the decimal to binary conversion as displayed in the below image.

```
class Solution{

public:
  string findDigitsInBinary(int n){
    string ans;
    if(n == 0) return "0";

    while(n > 0){
      int rem = n % 2;
      ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem));
      n /= 2;
    }

    reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    return ans;
  }
};
```

I am unable to understand what is happening in the second statement of the while loop.

```
ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem));
```

Here is my interpretation of this code.

Suppose I take the value of n as 5.

- Now for the first iteration of while loop, 5 > 0.
- rem = 5%2 = 1;
- In the ans string, '0' + 1(rem) i.e. "01" will be stored.
- n = 5/2 = 2
- Now, for second iteration, 2 > 0.
- rem = 2 % 2 = 0
- ans = "01" (already stored) + '0' + '0'(rem) => "0100"
- n = 2/2 = 1
- In final iteration, 1 > 0.
- rem = 1 % 2 = 1
- ans = "0100" + '0' + 1(rem) => "010001"
- n = 1 / 2 = 0
- Now on reversing the answer, it will become => 100010 but it is not the correct answer.

So, can anyone please explain where I am wrong?

Comment: very well put question.

Comment: since `rem = n % 2;` so it can be either `0` or `1`, `ans.push_back()` is going to take a `char` and with that char you're either adding `0` to it or `1`. `'0' + 0` gives `'0'` and `'0' + 1` gives `'1'`.

Comment: As frequently seen in questions with this title, there is no decimal to binary conversion here. There is *binary* to ASCII-encoded binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'0' + rem` is not doing what you think: `'0'` is a `char` literal and `rem` is an `int` value. Adding them together will result in an `int` that represents the ASCII value of either `'0'` or `'1'`.

More information: ["Convert an int to ASCII character"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629062/598696)