# How to print a char array and a certain character in it?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I've been reviewing my C++ lately. But I am running into a puzzle about printing a char array. The code is below:

```
int n = 5;
char *array1 = new char[n];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    array1[i] = (char)i;
cout << array1 << endl;
cout << array1[3] << endl;
cout << *array1 << endl;
```

None of the three cout lines works. Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: What is not working?  Does it compile?  If so, is it running?  If so, what is the output?

Comment: The `int` value `1` (for example) is not the same as the character `'1'`. [This ASCII (the most common character encoding) table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) should hopefully help you understand. And with that table in front of you, think about what happens if you do e.g. `1 + '0'`.

Comment: You are printing some none-printable characters.

Comment: You want to convert the number represented by i to a char? if i == 0, you want to print 0?

Comment: They work, you're just storing and printing non-printable characters.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @JLev That is correct.

Comment: @AnonMail Well It compiles and runs. But just gave nothing out.

Comment: @HolieChen try using this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629050/convert-an-int-to-ascii-character

Comment: @JLev Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array1[0] == 0`. `cout << array1` interprets `array1` as a pointer to a NUL-terminated string, and since the very first character is in fact NUL, the string is empty.

`cout << array1[3]` does print a character with ASCII code 3. It's a non-printable character, not visible to a naked eye. Not sure what output you expected to see there.

Answer (score 0):

As a separate answer, it seems you're trying to get a string which has the following : array = "1234....(n-1)"

Try :

```
for (int i = 0; i<(n-1); i++)
    array1[i] = (char)i - '0';
```

Comment: Should be '+' I suppose?

Comment: If its ' - ' ,this is what it does : `(ASCII value of n) - (ASCII value of 0) = n` .
So if its the number 0, it becomes `(ascii of 0) - (ascii of 0) =0` itself.

Please up vote incase I helped ^_^

Comment: I don't think so. Because (char)i means "character with ascii code of i" but not "ascii code of character 'i' ". So it should be '+'.