# Sending a fixed size UDP packet

Tags: c++, visual-c++, udp

I am writing a C++ program to send a UDP packet of 10 bytes.
The packet consists of 3 parts:

1 byte - a single number from 0-9

1 byte - a single number from 0-2

8 bytes - a number from 0 to max value of uint64

Lets say for example the numbers are 2, 0 and 14829735431805717965.
What I am doing at the moments is sending those numbers as variables to an ostringstream, which i read from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629050/convert-an-int-to-ascii-character) should convert the values to ASCII for serialization.

```
ostringstream str1;
uint8_t byte1 = 2;
uint8_t byte2 = 0;
uint64_t bytes = 14829735431805717965;


str1 << byte1<< byte2 << bytes;
string result = str1.str();
const char *pchar = result.c_str();
```

The above code demonstrates my process to make it compatible with the sendto() method. However when I do `sizeof(str1)` I get 152, even thought separately those variables add up to 10 bytes (1+1+8). When I do `sizeof(result)` and `sizeof(pchar)` I get 28 and 4 respectively - nothing remotely resembling my 10 bytes. I can only figure my method of doing this is wrong somehow - is the `uint64_t bytes` each number converted to separate ASCII which adds up to 150 or something?
I have looked around for similar problems, but to no avail.

Comment: I don't think `sizeof` means what you think it means.

Comment: Oh okay, noticed that sizeof evaluates the size of the data type and on compile-time, so I got that wrong indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I do sizeof(str1) I get 152

That is because you are obtaining the byte size of the `ostringstream` object itself. `ostringstream` has many data members in it besides just the pointer to the character data. You are looking for the byte size of the actual character data. `ostringstream` doesn't provide that size directly.

> even thought separately those variables add up to 10 bytes (1+1+8).

The raw variables do, yes.  But, by using `operator<<`, you are serializing their values to a `string`, where each numeric digit becomes its own character in the string, so the total byte size of the final character data will be more like 22, not 10.

> When I do sizeof(result) and sizeof(pchar) I get 28 and 4 respectively

Again, because you are obtaining the byte size of the `string` object itself (which also has other data members besides just the pointer to the character data), and the byte size of a raw pointer itself respectively.  You are looking for the byte size of the character data that the `string` internally points to.

`result.c_str()` will return a pointer to the actual character data, and `result.size()` will give you the proper byte size for that data.

> I can only figure my method of doing this is wrong somehow

Using `operator<<` is the completely wrong solution in this situation.  To put *binary* data into an `ostream`, use its `write()` method instead, eg:

```
uint8_t byte1 = 2;
uint8_t byte2 = 0;
uint64_t bytes = 14829735431805717965;

ostringstream str1;
str1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&byte1), sizeof(byte1));
str1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&byte2), sizeof(byte2));
str1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bytes), sizeof(bytes));

string result = str1.str();
sendto(..., result.c_str(), result.size(), ...);
```

Personally, I would suggest using a byte-aligned struct instead:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct packet {
    uint8_t byte1;
    uint8_t byte2;
    uint64_t bytes;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

packet p;
p.byte1 = 2;
p.byte2 = 0;
p.bytes = 14829735431805717965;

sendto(..., reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packet), sizeof(packet), ...);
```

Or, worse case, just use a simple byte array:

```
char packet[10];

uint8_t byte1 = 2;
uint8_t byte2 = 0;
uint64_t bytes = 14829735431805717965;

memcpy(&packet[0], &byte1, sizeof(byte1));
memcpy(&packet[1], &byte2, sizeof(byte2));
memcpy(&packet[2], &bytes, sizeof(bytes));
/* or:
*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&packet[0]) = byte1;
*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&packet[1]) = byte2;
*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&packet[2]) = bytes;
*/

sendto(..., packet, sizeof(packet), ...);
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, really aprecciate it!